# How to read websocket data using Apache Flink

Tags: java, websocket, apache-flink

I am trying to read data from `websocket` using `Apache Flink`

My Flink job is connecting to websocket but it is not pulling data from websocket.

below is the sample code that I have tried to connect to websocket using Apache flink API

the run() `method` in the `RichSourceFunction` neither executing nor throwing any error.

```
@Slf4j
public class Main {

    public static final int CHECKPOINTING_INTERVAL_MS = 5000;
    private static final String JOB_NAME = "Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton";

    /**
     * Main Flink job.
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        env.setParallelism(4);

        ParameterTool paramTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(paramTool);

        DataStreamSource<String> mySocketStream = env.addSource(new MyWebSocketSourceFunc());
        mySocketStream.map(new MapIt()).print();
//        mySocketStream.print();

        env.enableCheckpointing(CHECKPOINTING_INTERVAL_MS);
        env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.noRestart());
        env.execute(JOB_NAME);
    }

    public static class MyWebSocketSourceFunc extends RichSourceFunction<String> {
        private boolean running = true;
        transient AsyncHttpClient client;
        transient BoundRequestBuilder boundRequestBuilder;
        transient WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder webSocketListener;
        private BlockingQueue<String> messages = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);

        @Override
        public void run(SourceContext<String> ctx) throws Exception {
            WebSocketUpgradeHandler webSocketUpgradeHandler = webSocketListener.addWebSocketListener(
                    new WebSocketListener() {

                        private final ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper();

                        private String getRsvpId(String payload) {
                            try {
                                Map map = myMapper.readValue(payload, Map.class);
                                Object rsvpId = map.get("rsvp_id");
                                return rsvpId != null ? rsvpId.toString() : "NOT FOUND";
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                log.error("Mapping failed, returning 'null'");
                                return "NULL";
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onClose(WebSocket webSocket, int i, String s) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextFrame(String payload, boolean finalFragment, int rsv) {
                            log.debug("onTextFrame({}), rsvp_id={}", hash(payload), getRsvpId(payload));
                            if (payload != null) {
                                try {
                                    messages.put(payload);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    log.error("Interrupted!", e);
                                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).build();
            boundRequestBuilder.execute(webSocketUpgradeHandler).get();

            while (running) {
                ctx.collect(messages.take());
            }
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            log.info("cancel function called");
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            log.info("open function called");
            super.open(parameters);
            client = Dsl.asyncHttpClient();
            boundRequestBuilder = client.prepareGet("ws://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps");
            webSocketListener = new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder();
        }

        private String hash(String input) {
            if (input == null) {
                return "-- NULL --";
            }

            try {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md.update(input.getBytes());
                byte[] digest = md.digest();
                return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest).toUpperCase();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                log.error("Cound not instantiate MD5", e);
                return "--NOT CALCULATED--";
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MapIt extends RichMapFunction<String, String> {

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        @Override
        public String map(String value) throws Exception {
            Map<String, Object> mapped = objectMapper.readValue(value, Map.class);
            Object rsvp = mapped.get("rsvp_id");
            return rsvp != null ? rsvp.toString() : "null" ;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the reference document that I have followed to implement this job
[Referance](https://gist.github.com/tonvanbart/17dc93be413f7c53b76567e10b87a141)

TYIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink includes a built-in socket source connector. You'll find [an example showing how to use it in the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/overview/#example-program). That's going to be easier than debugging this other implementation.

Also be aware that using sockets in production applications is not recommended, since they are unable to provide any fault tolerance guarantees (because they cannot support checkpointing).

Comment: Thank you @David Anderson for your answer.